# How to remove all automatic formatting of <address> tag?

Tags: html, css

I am using normalize.css but I still have trouble when using the `<address>` tag to specify the author of an article:

```
<address rel="author">My Name</address>
```

At least in Firefox, it seems to turn it into a block level element, and adds `italic` to `font-style`.

I have no idea what else it's doing to it.

How can I remove all automatic styles for the `<address>` tag that browsers may add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `address` has this properties:

```css
address {
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

So if you want to reset `address`, set `font-style` to `normal`:

```css
address {
  font-style: normal
}
```

```html
<address rel="author">My Name</address>
```

If you don't want to give support to IE then you can use the `initial` value to specific properties (in this case `font-style`) or to all properties using `all` property

```css
address {
  all: initial
}
```

```html
<address rel="author">My Name</address>
```

**NO,TE** - the rule to display it is up to you but if you look at CSS resets, you'll see `address` as `display:block`

Comment: I found out while debugging a design that `<address>` also has `margin-bottom: 16px` as default. (Tested: Chrome, Firefox) So this is another property some people will need to use `initial` on to get it looking as desired. This strikes me as a strange default, since an address can be displayed literally anywhere. If you have a vertical list of contact info like: *address, phone, website*, there will be an unexpected gap only between *address* and *phone* if you use the tag. That's the web for ya, I guess. And even now in 2023, the resets I've seen don't initialize this property of `<address>`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/initial) keyword:

```
address { all: initial; }
```

This will remove the styles applied by the user agent stylesheet, such as `display: block` for `div`.

The use of `initial` is not limited to `all`. It can be used to "turn off" specific properties as well:

```
address { display: initial; }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I remove all automatic styles for the `<address>` tag that browsers may add?

You can't. You don't remove browser default styles. You override them.

So in your own stylesheet, set the rules for `<address>` as you wish.

The most current version of [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) (v4.1.1) doesn't contain any `<address>` rules, so no need to make any changes there.

You can get an idea of recommended default styles for browsers here:

- [Appendix D. Default style sheet for HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html)

You'll notice that `<address>` has `display: block` and `font-style: italic` applied.

Comment: *You can't*. Actually, you can. Whether or not you really want to is a good question though.

Comment: @torazaburo, I thought about that after reading your answer. But concluded that UA styles aren't really being *removed*. They're still being overridden by author styles.

Comment: That's a fine distinction. Isn't setting a property back to its initial value for all intents and purposes semantically identical to removing the relevant UA rules?

Comment: @torazaburo, the UA default stylesheet is a CSS file, just like an author's external stylesheet. Setting a CSS property to `initial` in an embedded or inline style doesn't *remove* the external stylesheet. It overrides it. I think the same logic applies to author styles vis-a-vis UA styles.

Comment: Overall, however, I think the distinction is too technical and insignificant to matter. The answer to your last comment could very well be Yes.